# Syntax to Output Email by Razor in ASP.net

Tags: c#, razor

Lets say 
`{
string domain="domain.com";
}`

I like to output

`webmaster@domain.com`, so I use

`webmaster@@domain` not working

Please advice correct syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest ways I can think of:

```
webmaster@@@domain
```

-or-

```
@("webmaster@" + domain)
```

Comment: have to say, neither answer looks good and simple, but yours are shorter and more easy to use

Comment: Added another way, I don't like it, but it's even simpler.

Comment: Three `@` like `@@@` not work at all, it outputs two `@` but output the variable literally.

Answer (score 3):

Not the easiest way, maybe, but I would try

```
@Html.Raw(string.Format("webmaster@{0}", domain))
```

As (smartly) noticed by OP

```
@string.Format("webmaster@{0}", domain)
```

Comment: You will not need the ';' at the end, that will just show as markup.

Comment: `@string.Format("webmaster@{0}", domain)` is enough, no need for `Html.Raw()` since no `<>"'` in the domain anyway